# Writing in parallel of a circuit/image

Tags: circuitikz

Hi everyone here is the where I would like the text to go:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}  
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contenido} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{figure} [ht]
\begin{circuitikz}  
 \fill[red!20] (3.1,1.3) rectangle (2.9,2.7); 

\draw (0,-1.5) 
to [V, v=$V_i$,invert] (0,3)
to [short] (3,3)  
(3,3) to [short] (6,3)  
to [battery, label = 1V] (6,1)  
(3,1) to [R=$1k\Omega $,v = $V_o$,*-*] (6,1)  
(6,1) node[label={[font=\footnotesize]right:\textbf{B}}] {} to [R=$2k\Omega$] (6,-1.5) 
(3,1) to [R=$2k\Omega$] (3,-1.5) 
(0,-1.5) to [short] (3,-1.5) 
(3,-1.5) to [short] (6,-1.5) 
(3,-1.5) -- (3,-1.7) node[ground]{} 
;
\draw 
(3,3) to [short, -o] (3,2.5)  
(3,1)  node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:\textbf{A}}] {} to [short,-o]  (3,1.5) 
(3,2.5) to [open, v = $V_\gamma$] (3,1.5) 
; 

\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

I'm looking of it to look like this:

[image]

I have the circuit inside an image because I thought it might help.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Just add these plots, e.g.add  `\begin{scope}[xshift=7.5cm]
\foreach \Y in {0,1,2}
{\draw plot[smooth,domain=0:pi,samples=17]
(\x,{0.6*sin(110*\x)+0.4*rnd*sin(160*\x)+1.2*\Y-1});}
\end{scope}` before `\end{circuitikz}`. But please consider to look a bit at the answers you received, in particular at the suggestions how to make the code cleaner. The intentions behind these suggestions are good, you will ultimately be able to avoid a lot of hassle if you now start to do these things in a more structured and modular way.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what is your problem. In your previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522266/moving-circuits/522289#522289) you got two solution, how to add a another image to your figure. What is now different?

Comment: I edited the question, maybe I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: @JulioOrtegón this is not LaTeX related, but EE-related... Notice that if you change from the multi ground drawing as you have in the pasted image to your single-ground one, you **have** to add a connection dot to the 4-way connection. Otherwise it's not clear that you have a connection and not a wire crossing there! (I have my electronics lecturer hat on now ;-))

Comment: I wonder, why you not use accepted answer on you previous question(s) and persist at you original code, which at least has wrong notation of units ...

Comment: Sorry you're I've been running with this code, that's why I haven't change that. However I'm know getting into the details, like the unit ones or making my code cleaner. In a future post you will see those changes. Thanks for the advices.

Comment: @Rmano You're right, I will change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `paracol` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}  
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contenido} 
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document} 
\setcolumnwidth{0.65\textwidth,0.35\textwidth}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{figure} [ht]
\begin{circuitikz}  
 \fill[red!20] (3.1,1.3) rectangle (2.9,2.7); 

\draw (0,-1.5) 
to [V, v=$V_i$,invert] (0,3)
to [short] (3,3)  
(3,3) to [short] (6,3)  
to [battery, label = 1V] (6,1)  
(3,1) to [R=$1k\Omega $,v = $V_o$,*-*] (6,1)  
(6,1) node[label={[font=\footnotesize]right:\textbf{B}}] {} to [R=$2k\Omega$] (6,-1.5) 
(3,1) to [R=$2k\Omega$] (3,-1.5) 
(0,-1.5) to [short] (3,-1.5) 
(3,-1.5) to [short] (6,-1.5) 
(3,-1.5) -- (3,-1.7) node[ground]{} 
;
\draw 
(3,3) to [short, -o] (3,2.5)  
(3,1)  node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:\textbf{A}}] {} to [short,-o]  (3,1.5) 
(3,2.5) to [open, v = $V_\gamma$] (3,1.5) 
; 
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure} 
\switchcolumn
\begin{eqnarray*}
   &e + f+l+k+p+h\\
   &e + f+l+k+p+h+t+r\\
   &e + f+l+k+p+h+w+f+r+t+y+b\\
   &c=a+b
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Units should be write upright ... see my answer, where is used `siunitx` syntax.

Comment: @Zarko, Absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

As starting point .. I left to write real equation to you. Note: see used `siunitx` units in equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[siunitx, american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, backgrounds, fit, shapes}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ c >{$}c<{$} }
    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(auxA)]
\draw   (0,0)   coordinate (A)
                to [V=$V_i$,invert] ++ (0, 6)
                to [short,-*]       ++ (2, 0) coordinate (aux1)
                to [short,-o]       ++ (0,-1) 
                to [open,v=$V_\gamma$]  ++ (0,-1)
                to [short,o-*]      ++ (0,-1) coordinate[label=left:A] (auxA)
                to [R=2<\kilo\ohm>,-*]  ++ (0,-3) node[ground]{}
                to [short]  (A)
        (aux1)  to [short]          ++ (2,0)
                to [battery,l=1<\volt>] ++ (0,-3)
                to [R=2<\kilo\ohm>] ++ (0,-3)
                to [short]          ++ (-2,0)
        (auxA)  to [R=1<\kilo\ohm>,v=$V_0$,-*] ++ (2,0) coordinate[label=right:B] (auxB)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
    &   \begin{gathered}
    V_i \ll 0 \to D_1(\text{off})      \\
    V_B = V_i - \SI{1}{\volt}           \\
    V_A = V_B \frac{\SI{2}{\kilo\ohm}}{\SI{1}{\kilo\ohm}+\SI{2}{\kilo\ohm}} = \dots\\
    xxx= ...\\
    yyy= ...\\
    V_d < 0 \to\frac{1}{3} ... V_i <-\SI{2}{\volt}
        \end{gathered}
\end{tabular}   
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have finished my votes. Excuse me. It is a great code. There is a ugly `<< `. Please, can you put,  `\ll ` instead?

Comment: @Sebastiano, I couldn't remember the name for `<<`! Thank you very much! Corrected. You vote  too much ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for granted my request. In all sincerity, my aim is to vote positively for everyone. I must always reward those who dedicate their precious time to others.

Comment: @Sebastiano, you are welcome! Happy, Prosper and Healthy New Year!

Comment: This is into chat: To all the friends of TeX.SE., for all those who are in suffering, who are not comforted by anyone, who do not enjoy good health, who do not find comfort, I wish you with all my heart a peaceful and good beginning of the year, be it a year of spiritual gathering and a year of good intentions for each of us. I always wish you every good and thank you for what you have done for me. Happy New Year.